# How to parse nested div's in Android using JSOUP?

Tags: android, jsoup

I have following html code:

```
  <div id="app"> 
<div data-reactroot id="timetable-content-holder">
<div class="top-bar"> ... </div> 
<h2>I need it </h2> 
<div class="timetable-holder gr-holder"> 
<div class="timetable-day gr"> 
<div class = "timetable-day-title"> Daily </dv> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
     </div>
```

I need to parse `h2` and text inside `timetable-day-title`. I cannot write select method. This is my trials:

```
Elements elements = document.select("div#app > div#timetable-content-holder > h2");
```

But `elements` size is zero. How to write document's select method in my case?

Answer (score 4):

You can select tag by comma separator  whichever you want

```
 String html =" <div id=\"app\"> \n" +
                 "<div data-reactroot id=\"timetable-content-holder\">\n" +
                 "<div class=\"top-bar\"> ... </div> \n" +
                 "<h2>I need it </h2> \n" +
                 "<div class=\"timetable-holder gr-holder\"> \n" +
                 "<div class=\"timetable-day gr\"> \n" +
                 "<div class = \"timetable-day-title\"> Daily </dv> \n" +
                 "</div> \n" +
                 "</div> \n" +
                 "</div> \n" +
                 "     </div> ";

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elements = document.select("#app #timetable-content-holder h2,.timetable-day-title ");
        for (Element element:elements){
            System.out.println(element.text());
        }
```

**Update** 
Try this code for calling from url

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://YourURL.com").get();
```

Output:

```
I need it
Daily
```

Comment: Yes,it works. But you show me the example with ready ready html code. But I tried that with URL that I have,but it didn't work. Can you show me how to parse html and get there that strings?

Comment: Your method works only if html is written as on your first version of answer. It successfully shows all needed strings. But if i connect through the URL it does not work, but title of site is shown. How can I send you url?

Comment: @andy11 what's the url can you update the question i'm happy to help.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help. But I don't want url to be public. Is there a way to send you url privately on stackoverflow?

Comment: Have you tried? I would accept your answer, if you could help me